# How to collect data from table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to collect data from inputs (inputs are in table which has id=tbl_bbmd and  unknown number of rows , like on picture)
[image]

I need to collect data from inputs cells and concaneta them. How to iterate through this table and collect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted a single concatenated string of all the values, you can do this:

```
var result = $('#tbl_bbmd input').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

If you wanted an Array of strings per row, you can do this:

```
var result = [];
$('#tbl_bbmd tr').each(function() {
    result.push( $(this).find('input').map(function(){ return this.value; }).get().join(',') );
});
```

If you wanted the data serialized, you can do this:

```
var result = $('#tbl_bbmd input').serialize();
```